# Перевод данных с использованием кириллицы из wstring в string

Tags: c++

Всем добрый день,
возникли проблемы с переводом наименований файлов с wstring в string, так как некоторые файлы имеют в названии кириллицу. Пробовал несколько способов перевода,
ниже приведен тот который мне кажется более оптимальным. Но не получается довести до ума перевод кириллицы, уйти от разных типов данных нет возможности так как в основном проекте несколько разных функций использующих эти типы данных, и которым  нет пока возможности сделать замену.

```
#include <iostream>
#include<string>
#include <codecvt>
#include <windows.h>

std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8_utf16<wchar_t>> converter;

int main()
{
    SetConsoleCP(1251);
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
    std::wstring s = L"3-3 — копия.txt\n";
    std::wcout << s;
    std::string ws = converter.to_bytes(s);
    std::wstring std = converter.from_bytes(ws);
    std::cout << ws;
    std::wcout << std;
}
```

Comment: *"возникли проблемы"* - какие проблемы? *"не получается"* - что не получается?

Comment: единственный нормальный стандартный способ конвертировать широкую строку в обычную — это Сишный `wcstombs`... В С++ для него обёртки нет. Грустно, но факт... В твоём случае очевидная проблема в том, что ты считаешь, что обычная строка у тебя в utf-8, что на win, очевидно, не так... ещё одна проблема в том, что нельзя одновременно использовать широкие потоки и обычные, но это уже минорщина...